# show panel when click on link button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, ajax

I want to show/hide panel on click of a link button. This is working fine when i use it on simple page but when i try it on the page that is used as Master Page then it's not working.

My codes:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master_Institute.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frm_Student_Renewal_Reg.aspx.cs" Inherits="frm_Student_Renewal_Reg" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .panel{
            display:none;
        }
        .style1{
            width: 620%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#Link1").click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $('#panelText').slideToggle('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="Link1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">
                    Using slideToggle
                </asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
                <asp:Panel ID="panelText" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc turpis nunc, placerat ac, bibendum non, pellentesque nec, odio.
                </asp:Panel> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: add the ClientIDMode="Static" - property to your Panel

Comment: Now why the flag is down for this question?

Answer (score 2):

All the ids of the controls are automatically created base on ID and on other page that are on. When you have a single page is very possible the `Link1` to be rendered again as `Link1` but when you add it inside a master page, then asp.net to avoid conflicts is add some more names on front, eg the name of the place holder.

Now practically, you need to have on client side javascript code, the final rendered ids, and this can be get using the `Link1.ClientID`.
So on every line that you have to get the ids you use it as

```
$("#<%=Link1.ClientID%>").click(function(evt) {
```

and you do that for all your asp.net controls that you use on the javascript.

You can also set `ClientIDMode="Static"` but do that you can not use the same control two times on the same page, and you also must take care other controls to not have the same ids.

The [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)=Static property says to asp.net to keep the id that you have set and not make a new one dynamically. This property introducing on asp.net version 4.